# Preventing exception from lack of internet connectivity

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I have a simple Windows Form application. I have used a Timer and on Timer interval I am checking online database for values and updating it on the form.

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick 

    Try
        String ConnectionString = globalConnString
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT AnnouncementID, AnnoucementText FROM tblAnnouncements"
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)    
        conn.Open()

        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn)

        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("Announcements")
        adapter.Fill(ds)

        UpdateForm(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
            LogError("Timer_Tick", ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Now sometimes the internet is disconnected or there is very slow internet. For that I have created a function as below,

```
Public Function CheckInternetConnection() As Boolean
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable = True Then
            Return My.Computer.Network.Ping("8.8.8.8")
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try        
End Function
```

This function is pinging google public DNS but in my application this is the IP address of my database server. I have wrapped the functionality inside Timer_Tick inside CheckInternetConnection so that when there is internet connection only then the database operation is made.

Now problem I am facing is that when I switch internet (using two different wifi conenctions) and when I turn on and off the internet then very rarely the code is broken and exception is created for line adapter.Fill(ds). My guess is that it is because at the start of function there is internet connectivity available and the condition for internet check is passed. When program starts to execute database operation then at that point rarely internet is gone so the program raises exception.

The example I have given is for one function and the actual application (which is quite big and written long time ago) is like this and I have to fix the connectivity issue within the same code. How can I make this fool proof that no database code is ever reached when there is no internet connectivity?

Comment: I think you cannot get rid of the exception handler in any case. When something could happen outside the control of your application (like a drop in connectivity) you have no choiche than to handle a possible exception. It is not a case that they are called Exceptions.

Comment: @Steve, yes you are right in a way but being a programmer I want to put every possible checks for this. I just don't want to execute code when there is no internet connectivity. If after all the solution it still breaks then yes there will be exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to try multiple times. E.g.

```
int numTries = 3;
while (numTries > 0) {
  numTries--;

  try {
    // open connection, fill 
    // your code
    break; // got here means success
  } catch {
    if (numTries == 0)
        throw; // propagate exception to next level
    Thread.Sleep(500); // optional sleep
  }
}
```

Comment: i thought of the same and was implementing the same. Good to know someone think like me. Will wait for more options before selecting it as answer though. Thank you for this answer.